# Map/Collect first true result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider the following

```
users.collect do |user|
  user.favorite_song.presence
end.compact.first
```

In this case, I want the first favorite song I encounter among my users.

Can this be written in a nicer way?

I tried

```
users.find do |user|
  user.favorite_song.presence
end
```

But it returns the first user with a favorite song, rather than the favorite song itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the `users` array isn't too big, your first solution is fine, and can be rewritten like this:

```
users.map(&:favorite_song).compact.first
```

You can also modify your second approach as follows:

```
users.find { |user| user.favorite_song.present? }.favorite_song
```

Both of these solutions assume that there exists a `favorite_song` in some user and will raise an exception if there isn't.  You can elegantly avoid this with `try` (Rails only):

```
users.find { |user| user.favorite_song.present? }.try(:favorite_song)
```

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
users.each do |user|
  break user.favorite_song if user.favorite_song.present?
end
```

Will return `user.favorite_song` if condition is `true` otherwise will return `users`

Comment: +1 for the answer. using break, I guess an optimal solution. :)

Comment: Returning a collection of users is not acceptable. Either a favorite song or nil.

Comment: Then using `find` is your solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
favorite_song = nil
users.map do |user|
  favorite_song = user.favorite_song
  break if favorite_song
end
```

Comment: I think this involves too much code regarding others answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with

```
users.map{|user| user.favorite_song}.compact.first
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Ruby 2.0 you can use [Enumerator::Lazy#lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) to solve this more cleanly and efficiently:

```
users.lazy.map(&:favorite_song).find(&:present?)
```

This is more efficient because it will only call `favorite_song` on users until it finds one that's present. It's cleaner because it's more concise and `lazy` is self documenting of the intention.